# matlab - save array every nth step

Tags: matlab, loops, variables, save

Suppose I have a large array of numbers
    x = (1,2,3,4......2000)

I can update the value every step of a loop, so at t = 1
    x(t) = (2,3,4,5......2001)

and at t = 2
    x(t) = (3,4,5,6......2002)

and so on. What I want to do is every nth step (say, every 10th or 20th it does not matter yet) is to save x as a distinct entry in the workspace. Say, if I update x every 50 steps I will have in the workspace

```
x0 = (1,2,3.....)
x50 = (51,52,53,....)
x100 = (101,102,103...)
```

and so on. (The actual values of x will change according to a formula)

thanks
William

Comment: Can you explain WHY do you need to split `x` to different variables instead of using different columns/rows in `x`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment I have changed this answer.

```
k = 10;
x_history = NaN(k,length(x))
t = 0;
while (!stopping_condition)
    if mod(t,k) == 0
        x_history(t,:) = x;
    end
    x = update(x)
    t = t + 1
end
```

where `update` is the function of how `x` changes at each timestep

Comment: Hi Dan, thanks for that. However, my actual problem is that simple! I have a set of values of x which are updated constantly. I need to snapshot these every so often so I can keep the values and use them later. regards,

Comment: Then use reshape and a *single* numerical matrix

Comment: Hi Dan, I don't think this is a suitable solution to the problem at hand, but thanks anyway. regards,

Comment: @William which is exactly why I recommended that you better explain the problem. If the problem is to partition 2000 numbers into bins of 50 each then this is absolutely the correct solution. If the problem is more complicated than that, then you need to explain precisely how so.

Comment: Hi Dan. Sorry for the confusion. At time zero, I have a vector, x, of a particular length, say length 1,000. That is, there are 1,000 unique values that make up the vector x at time zero. A loop updates all these values, so that x is constantly changing. So I wish to save x(t) in my workspace so I can manipulate it later. If the time, t, is 0, I will have a vector x0 saved; if the time, t, is 30000 I will have a vector x30000 saved. All these vectors will be the same length, but with different values. kind regards

Comment: @William see the edit. You still want a single numerical number

Comment: What is needed is, at the end of the loop, a list of vectors. If my loop is of length 100 and I make the decision to save every 10 steps, I will have 10 vectors saved. regards

Comment: @William just use `mod` to onlu save it every `k` iterations. See edit again